# Eclipse xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" not recognized?

Tags: java, xml, jsf

I am having issues with loading the JSF Library in my Eclipse project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
      <title>#{msgs.windowTitle}</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
      #{msgs.pageTitle}
      <h:form>
         <h:dataTable value="#{tableData.names}" var="name">
            <h:column>
               #{name.last},
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
               #{name.first}
            </h:column>
         </h:dataTable>
      </h:form>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

it seems like the `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"` isn't being recognized/resolved ? When I run the **index.xhtml** file in Eclipse, i get the following output:

```
#{msgs.pageTitle} #{name.last}, #{name.first}
```

rather than the expected output data tables from my class files.

Below is my faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
   version="2.0">
   <application>
      <resource-bundle>
         <base-name>com.corejsf.messages</base-name>
         <var>msgs</var>
      </resource-bundle>
   </application>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: The URI does not ship with any resource. Check.

Comment: @hakre: a Facelets taglib URI does not necessarily represent a reachable Internet address. The URI is merely definied in taglib XML file deployed with the webapp. It has no relationship with the EL expressions being evaluated or not. Your comment makes therefore no utter sense.

Comment: mildse7en, this problem has got nothing to do with the taglib URI. It has anything to do with EL. You'd need to provide more information about the project setup (config? settings? buildpath? libraries? etc) and the environment (IDE version? JSF make/version? server make/version? etc) used than only a Facelets file.

Comment: i'm using Eclipse Java EE Juno with Tomcat 7.0

Comment: Given the complete lack of information about how you registered the JSF servlet in `web.xml`, may I assume that you have indeed not registered it at all? Which book/tutorial exactly are you following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I was actually running the XHTML file rather than the entire project. Running the entire project works perfectly!

Comment: (...) Which tutorial exactly are you following that didn't made that clear at all?